# TFS 2013 + GIT, check in policies

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm playing with Visual Studio 2013 and TFS 2013 (RC) and I can't find a way how can I use custom check-in policies. I use GIT as source control.

I would like to have policy which will check if references in all project in sln are meeting some rules. (only two paths or project references can be used)

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html) like [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html) in an intermediate local repo:

- you push to that repo (protected by gitolite)
- which in turn, if the policies are enforced, can push to a target repo, like one hosted by http://tfs.visualstudio.com.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this myself yet, but there is [a blog post about how to do this](http://almsports.net/tfs-server-side-check-in-policy-for-git-repositories/1025/) on the TFS server using the Tfs-Git ProcessEvent hook. We are starting to switch to Git from TFVC at my company and have 30+ checkin policies, so we'll likley be trying this solution out soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think that because this is a really Git repository on the server, perhaps you should write a git hook : http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: does it work? have you tried write git hooks to tfs?